# Strange behavior startActivityForResult from Fragment

Tags: android

I have a Activity FirstActivity.Java that has a FragmentA.Java which calls startActivityForResult(). SecondActivity.Java call finish() but onActivityResult get called one time as FragmentA calls startActivityForResult() which is written in FragmentA. Java and never after as SecondActivity.Java calls finish().

**FragmentA:**

```
Intent popup = new Intent(getActivity(),
PopupActivity.class);
popup.putExtra(PopupActivity.EXTRA_URL, url + "&_resolve=popupResolve");
startActivityForResult(popup, 222);

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 222){
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            executeJS((Uri) data.getSerializableExtra(PopupActivity.EXTRA_RESOLVE));
        }
    }
}
```

**SecondActivity:**

```
Intent data = new Intent();
Uri uri = Uri.parse(mUrl);
data.putExtra(EXTRA_RESOLVE, uri);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
finish();
```

Comment: First of all replace this code data.putExtra(EXTRA_RESOLVE, uri.toString()); and executeJS(Uri.parse(data.getStringExtra(PopupActivity.EXTRA_RESOLVE)));.

Comment: where is onActivityResult overiden? in a Activity or a Fragment?

Comment: @pskink I try to overiden in both, but now only in a Fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a Fragment call startActivityForResult(), when finish the next activity, onActivityResult method is called in the first Activity, not in the fragment.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't happen. onActivityResult is called as a Fragment start to open SecondActivity, after startActivityForResult, may be after FirstActivity calls onPause or something else